# Xamarin deploy error HE0004 DADocSetManagement

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I updated Xcode from 9.3 to 9.4.1 and got the following error when trying to debug on my iPad that is attached to the Mac:

> error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'DADocSetManagement' (path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DADocSetManagement.framework/DADocSetManagement)

On the Mac, I have:

- Xamarin.iOS 11.12.0.4
- Xamarin.Mac 4.4.1.193

My Windows 10 machine also has the same version of Xamarin.iOS.

Any ideas why I am getting this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue my removing xCode and reinstalling it from the App Store.